# Unable to find error in php

Tags: php, compiler-errors

Can someone find any obvious errors in this code? The website doesn't load so I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the php. The website is blank and you can find any information of what the problem might be. This is just a small piece of code, but it's the only piece of code that includes php.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$dir = "sound";
$bucketsArrayString = "var buckets = [";
if (is_dir($dir))
{
  $bucket = "";
  $intensity = "";
  $position = "";
  $distance = "";

  echo "var soundTree = \n[";

  if ($dh = opendir($dir))
  {
    for($i = 0; ($file = readdir($dh)) !== false; )
    {
      if($file[0] != ".")
      {
        if($i > 0)
        {
          echo ",";
          $bucketsArrayString .= ", ";
        }
        echo "\n\t[";

            $bucketsArrayString .= "'$file'";
        $bucket = $file;

        $distances = array("close", "medium", "distant");
        for($j = 0; $j < count($distances); $j++)
        {
          if($j > 0)
            echo ",";
          echo "\n\t\t[";

          $distance = $distances[$j];

          $positions = array("back", "front", "left", "right");
          for($k = 0; $k < count($positions); $k++)
          {
            $position = $positions[$k];

            if($k > 0)
              echo ',';
            echo "\n\t\t\t[";           

                $intensities = array("often", "seldom");
                for($l = 0; $l < count($intensities); $l++)
                {
                $intensity = $intensities[$l];

                $folder = $dir . "/" . $bucket . "/" . $distance . "/" . $position . "/" . $intensity;
                if($l > 0)
                  echo ',';
                echo "\n\t\t\t\t[";

                $m = 0;

                if ($dirHandle = opendir($folder))
                {
                while (($fileHandle = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false)
                {

                if($fileHandle[0] != ".")
                {
                  if($m > 0)
                    echo ",";
                  echo "\n\t\t\t\t\t'" . $fileHandle . "'";
                  $m++;
                }
              }
              echo "\n\t\t\t\t]"
            }
            echo "\n\t\t\t]";
          }
          echo "\n\t\t]";
        }
        echo "\n\t]";
        $i++;
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
    $bucketsArrayString .= '];';
  }

  echo "\n];\n";
}

echo $bucketsArrayString;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 75 to this

```
 echo "\n\t\t\t\t]";       // missing semicolon
```

and add `}` at the end

```
echo $bucketsArrayString;
}                          // missing bracket
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

instead of:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

    `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
 instead of

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

then you will get all errors and warnings